# REST Service returns CORS? error - ColdFusion

Tags: rest, iis, coldfusion, cors, coldfusion-11

I create a REST service in CF11 and up until last night everything was working fine until I started getting CORS errors all over the place.

Long story short this is my code:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restPath="/testimonials">
  <cffunction name="getTestimonials" access="remote" returntype="any" httpMethod="GET" restPath="/getTestimonials">            
        <cfargument name="showRatings" type="numeric" restArgSource="Query" default="0">
        <cfargument name="siteID" type="numeric" restArgSource="Query" default="0">
        <cfargument name="pageID" type="numeric" restArgSource="Query" default="0">
.....
```

And I am calling it like this

```
<cfhttp url="http://dev.example.com/rest/api/testimonials/getTestimonials" method="GET" result="res">    
    <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="showRatings" value="0">
    <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="siteID" value="17">
    <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="pageID" value="2">    
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#res#">
```

And this is the return struct that I am getting back

```
struct
Charset     [empty string]
ErrorDetail     [empty string]
Filecontent     [empty string]
Header  HTTP/1.1 200 OK Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 08:14:02 GMT Content-Length: 0 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET server-error: true
Mimetype    Unable to determine MIME type of file.
Responseheader  
struct
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    POST,GET,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin     *
Content-Length  0
Date    Wed, 23 Sep 2015 08:14:02 GMT
Explanation     OK
Http_Version    HTTP/1.1
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Status_Code     200
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
server-error    true
Statuscode  200 OK
Text    YES
```

Nothing Changed as far as I know code-wise or on my IIS server to justify this error. I even added the code below in my web.config to try and enable CORS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What does the `server-error: true` mean? The webserver doesn't respond with content. The problem is most likely related to IIS. Put the `throwOnError="true"` in your `<cfhttp>` - just in case.

Comment: @AlexanderKwaschny I restarted the rest service through CF Admin and it started working again. I don't know if some of the calls to the rest service caused it to stop working... I am still looking into it.

Comment: I use ColdFusion 10 and occasionally get `server-error: true` with a `200 OK` response from the rest API.  It doesn't happen to all endpoints...just some of them but not always the same ones.  I need to re-initialize the rest service to fix it.  I don't know what causes it, but I've tinkered with max reuse connector settings (https://christierney.com/2014/12/09/max_reuse_connections-conundrum-coldfusion-11-tomcat-iis-connector/).  It's reduced the frequency of the error, but hasn't solved it completely.